# Powershell variable script

Tags: powershell

Another week another powershell question. First off thank you all for your help I am learning a lot and I am thinking that I know the answer but can't seem to get it out of my head into the script today.

I currently have this.

```
$user           = "user"
$pass1          = Read-Host "Enter Techops Password"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass1 -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential     = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $SecurePassword)
$querylist      = (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221110\VIPS\20221115_vips1.csv').ip
                  

$today          = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date)
Import-Module tm-device42
Connect-D42 -Credential $Credential 

$results = foreach ($ip in ($querylist)) {
            Get-vServerPrdFromPim {$_.ip}

            }


$results | Write-Output
```

The `$results | Write-output` wont be staying I'm just using it whilst building the script.

The `$querylist      = (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221110\VIPS\20221115_vips1.csv').ip` returns the correct info, currently a single IP address 10.10.10.1 (example)

However I get a result of product not found on the `Get-vServerPrdFromPim` (this is an internal custom made module) but if I do

`Get-vServerPrdFromPim 10.10.10.1` in powershell I get the answers that I would expect.

```
user> (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221110\VIPS\20221115_vips1.csv').ip
10.75.230.74
```

So I am assuming it is an issue with my foreach statement.

I am just wanting to pull the IP's from a large sheet and check them against a database and then output the data.

Am I correct in thinking that I haven't correctly formatted my foreach statement? If so how do I make $ip reference the info from $querylist?

Kind regards

-------------UPDATE --------------------

I have adjusted the following code as suggested

```
Get-vServerPrdFromPim $ip
```

So now the foreach loop looks like

```
$results = foreach ($ip in ($querylists)) {
            Get-vServerPrdFromPim $ip | select Name, ProductCode, NetAddr, InfrastructureOwner, OperatingSystemOwner 

            }
```

This seems to work fine for a file with a single IP address but when I add additional IP's to the CSV it only processes the first IP.

Will need to dig in further.

Further Update. As requested this is what the excel sheet looks like. This is just an extract.

Comment: Change `Get-vServerPrdFromPim {$_.ip}` to `Get-vServerPrdFromPim $ip`

Comment: Thank you @MathiasR.Jessen that solved it. Can you help clear up the difference between {$_.ip} compared to $ip. If you have a link to PowerShell syntax or similar that would be awesome. 

That solved it as you probably expected.

Comment: The following is helpful reading.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen are you able to offer any advice on my update please?

Comment: @asthmatic_weasel Hard to tell without seeing the updated CSV file :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you for replying I have updated the question with a sheet. I really appreciate any help you can offer me.

Comment: @asthmatic_weasel That's not the CSV file - that's a screenshot of Excel or a similar spreadsheet editor. Please show us the contents of _the file itself_. `Get-Content path\to\file.csv -Raw |Set-Clipboard` then paste it into your post

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake in my code. Thanks to @mathias and also other research. Code ended up being

```
$user           = "user"
$pass1          = Read-Host "Enter Techops Password"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass1 -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential     = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $SecurePassword)
$ips     = (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\user\Documents\20221110\VIPS\20221115_vips.csv').ip
                    

$today          = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date)
Import-Module device42
Connect-D42 -Credential $Credential 

$results = foreach ($ip in $ips){
            Get-vServerPrdFromPim $ip | select Name, ProductCode, NetAddr, InfrastructureOwner, OperatingSystemOwner 

            }
$results | Export-Csv C:\Users\user\Documents\20221110\D42_test.csv
```